# Magento 2 Mini cart items are shown twice

Tags: magento2, products, mini-cart

I have Magento 2 and I enabled ajax add to cart and the mini cart.  I added 5 products to my cart, it shows a count of 5 but when I click on the cart icon to show the listing it shows the product list twice.  The 5 products are shown and then the list is repeated although the cart total is correct.

Once I go to the checkout page the listing is correct.  Any come across this issue before?  Ideas where to look to track down what is going on?

Comment: Can you please share your issue with screenshots ?

Comment: Please try to remove Ajax add to cart extension or any third-party extensions which are related to mini-cart or add to cart feature and see. If it got fixed then you need to debug that extension and fix it.

Comment: This duplication of the cart items does always happen and when it does if I just reload the page then the cart items are displayed correctly.